# Jquery append() to ul not working with nested $.each loops

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, each, loading

I am currently having an issue with using JQuery with json data to append a calculated amount of `<li>` elements to a `<ul>`. Here is my code:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.hivemc.com/v1/game/timv", function(data) {

        $.each(data.achievements, function(key,value){

            var unlocked = "Locked";

            $.each(maindata.achievements, function(key2,value2){
                if(value.name == key2){
                    unlocked = "Unlocked";
                }
            });

            $("#achs").append("<li><p>" + value.publicname + "</p><span>"+ unlocked + "</span></li>");
        });
    });
```

As you can see, I am getting JSON data from a URL. In this, there is an array achievements. The variable `maindata` was set earlier from another $.getJSON().

For each achievement, I have to append a `<li>` element with the data of the achievement to a `<ul>` which has the id of `#achs`. However, in order to see if the achievement is unlocked, I have to check for the achievements name in the `maindata` JSON, meaning another $.each() loop inside the current $.each() loop.

Without the extra loop, the code works fine, and successfully forms a list of achievements and whether they are unlocked or not. However, whenever I add the extra $.each() back in again, it only works when I reload the page or go back and back onto it again.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am sure you can see I am not very experienced with JQuery. Also, I have been able to do this with just PHP, retrieving JSON data, but I wanted to see if using JQuery would be quicker loading than PHP.

The `maindata` JSON is retrieved from this code:`var maindata;

```
    $.getJSON("http://api.hivemc.com/v1/player/" + $user + "/timv", function(data) {
        $('#1').text(data.total_points);
        $('#2').text(data.i_points);
        $('#3').text(data.t_points);
        $('#4').text(data.d_points);
        $('#5').text(data.role_points);
        $('#6').text(data.most_points);

        maindata = data;

        if(data.detectivebook == true)
            $('#7').text("Yes");
        else
            $('#7').text("No");

        $flare = data.active_flareupgrade;
        $flare = $flare.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + $flare.slice(1).toLowerCase();
        $('#8').text($flare);
        $('#9').text(data.title);
        var d = new Date(data.lastlogin * 1000);
        var n = d.toISOString(); 
        $('#10').text(d.getDate() + "/" + d.getMonth() + "/" + d.getFullYear());

        $.getJSON("http://api.hivemc.com/v1/game/timv", function(data2) {

        $.each(data2.achievements, function(key,value){

            var unlocked = "Locked";

            $.each(maindata.achievements, function(key2,value2){
                if(value.name == key2){
                    unlocked = "Unlocked";
                }
            });

            $("#achs").append("<li><p>" + value.publicname + "</p><span>"+ unlocked + "</span></li>");
        });
    });
    });`
```

Thanks.

Comment: `if(value.name == key2){
                    unlocked = "Unlocked";
                }else{unlocked = "Locked"}`

Comment: Any error in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wait for your earlier AJAX call to complete before doing any processing that depends on the results of both calls:

```
var promise1 = $.getJSON(...);     // get maindata
var promise2 = $.getJSON(...);     // get data

$.when(promise1, promise2).then(function(maindata, data) {
    // do your processing here
    ...
});
```

NB: there's no need to supply callbacks to the `$.getJSON` calls - do the processing within the `.then` callback.

Comment: when I use both variables in the $.when() and try to retrieve its data from either maindata or data, it doesnt work, however when I only use 1 it does. Do you know why this may be?

Comment: @AlexBoullé I can think of no obvious reason - the above code is pretty much the canonical way of writing this

Comment: yeah I'm a bit stuck. I'll try and see if I've gone wrong somewhere else in my code as I no doubt have, and see if I can fix it.